# OpenCV Aruco pose estimation example code from Tutorial

Tags: opencv

I am trying to get basic pose estimation working with the Aruco library which is included in OpenCV.

What is wrong about the example http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html under

> A basic full example for pose estimation from single markers:

the code is as follows (composed out of the example code and some of my code to read out the camera Parameters and distortion coefficients):

```
// http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html
// 

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <vector>

#include "opencv2\Core\types.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

#include "opencv2/tracking.hpp"

#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>

#include <opencv2/aruco/charuco.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {


    printf("OpenCV: %s", cv::getBuildInformation().c_str());

    cv::VideoCapture inputVideo;
    inputVideo.open(0);
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;




    // camera parameters are read from somewhere
    ////readCameraParameters(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);

    cv::String filename = "C:\\C\\buildVs\\opencv-master\\samples\\cpp\\tutorial_code\\calib3d\\camera_calibration\\myCalibratedForBuiltinCamera.yml";

    float markerLength = 0.05f; // length in meters (?) of a marker

    // read calibration file
    //cout << endl << "Reading: " << endl;
    cv::FileStorage fs;
    fs.open(filename, cv::FileStorage::READ);


//  cv::Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;

    fs["Camera_Matrix"] >> cameraMatrix;
    fs["Distortion_Coefficients"] >> distCoeffs;



    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
    while (inputVideo.grab()) {
        cv::Mat image, imageCopy;
        inputVideo.retrieve(image);
        image.copyTo(imageCopy);
        std::vector<int> ids;
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > corners;
        cv::aruco::detectMarkers(image, dictionary, corners, ids);
        // if at least one marker detected
        if (ids.size() > 0) {
            cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(imageCopy, corners, ids);
            std::vector< cv::Mat > rvecs, tvecs;
            cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, 0.05, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
            // draw axis for each marker
            for (int i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++)
                cv::aruco::drawAxis(imageCopy, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs[i], tvecs[i], 0.1);
        }
        cv::imshow("out", imageCopy);
        char key = (char)cv::waitKey(2);
        if (key == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I copy this to a new project and try to use it with some aruco::DICT_6X6_250 markers it crashes.

One reason for this could be that the coefficients are in the wrong format, the calibration file I'm using has the following content(s):

```
%YAML:1.0
calibration_Time: "08/19/11 20:44:38"
nrOfFrames: 8
image_Width: 640
image_Height: 480
board_Width: 9
board_Height: 6
square_Size: 50.
FixAspectRatio: 1.
# flags:  +fix_aspectRatio +fix_principal_point +zero_tangent_dist
flagValue: 14
Camera_Matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 6.5746697810243404e+002, 0., 3.1950000000000000e+002, 0.,
       6.5746697810243404e+002, 2.3950000000000000e+002, 0., 0., 1. ]
Distortion_Coefficients: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 5
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -4.1802327018241026e-001, 5.0715243805833121e-001, 0., 0.,
       -5.7843596847939704e-001 ]
Avg_Reprojection_Error: 3.8441346462381665e-001
Per_View_Reprojection_Errors: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 8
   cols: 1
   dt: f
   data: [ 5.04357755e-001, 4.85754758e-001, 3.99563968e-001,
       4.13829178e-001, 3.53570908e-001, 3.21116358e-001,
       2.74473161e-001, 2.39761785e-001 ]
# a set of 6-tuples (rotation vector + translation vector) for each view
Extrinsic_Parameters: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 8
   cols: 6
   dt: d
   data: [ -7.8704123655486097e-002, -1.5922384772614945e-001,
       3.1166227207451498e+000, 2.4224388101960471e+002,
       1.1795590397660339e+002, 6.2576484126093249e+002,
       -1.4117480285164308e-001, -1.7917415443804836e-002,
       3.1333182268743949e+000, 2.5943034781849354e+002,
       1.4039780562976958e+002, 6.3848706527260981e+002,
       7.2230525186138789e-002, -7.5445981266787754e-002,
       1.5712860749221762e+000, 1.7426560451795339e+002,
       -1.9309240362258871e+002, 7.0891416556762647e+002,
       2.0367310600105853e-002, 6.8565520026996951e-002,
       -5.4313033031644169e-004, -2.0146314940404827e+002,
       -1.3305643514116997e+002, 7.4933554744027231e+002,
       -3.4468530027734055e-002, 2.1921265175331925e-002,
       -1.5731053528054522e+000, -1.1155718744299284e+002,
       2.0307615364261443e+002, 8.4915903914333899e+002,
       3.7425562109513817e-002, 7.4883169379022230e-002,
       -3.6031632305130512e-002, -2.0094505419395196e+002,
       -1.1627359108310560e+002, 9.2021583518760133e+002,
       6.8105689976949157e-002, 6.4426739692440949e-002,
       -7.0967130057087435e-002, -1.9233852871740035e+002,
       -1.0334652096641923e+002, 1.0755293563503658e+003,
       -5.8017546499862287e-002, -1.6909812666033443e-003,
       -1.5876137659782963e+000, -1.0242234847115104e+002,
       2.2583088401423066e+002, 1.1125972190244058e+003 ]
Image_points: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 8
   cols: 54
   dt: "2f"
   data: [ 5.58494690e+002, 3.55650085e+002, 5.13314697e+002,
       3.59107666e+002, 4.65728333e+002, 3.62133911e+002,
       4.15701111e+002, 3.65026459e+002, 3.64399353e+002,
       3.67339203e+002, 3.12101196e+002, 3.69211914e+002,
       2.59208405e+002, 3.70413513e+002, 2.07456192e+002,
       3.71175995e+002, 1.56619507e+002, 3.72176544e+002,
       5.60868713e+002, 3.08104828e+002, 5.15191772e+002,
       3.10485626e+002, 4.67032959e+002, 3.12660004e+002,
       4.16112152e+002, 3.14887177e+002, 3.64010712e+002,
       3.16825775e+002, 3.10712372e+002, 3.18640808e+002,
       2.56853943e+002, 3.20017365e+002, 2.04168182e+002,
       3.20908417e+002, 1.52469528e+002, 3.22105377e+002,
       5.62328369e+002, 2.58646881e+002, 5.16396301e+002,
       2.59919281e+002, 4.67907654e+002, 2.61257874e+002,
       4.16463440e+002, 2.62675537e+002, 3.63546570e+002,
       2.64064117e+002, 3.09528137e+002, 2.65489990e+002,
       2.54765533e+002, 2.66862030e+002, 2.01299225e+002,
       2.67997345e+002, 1.48913437e+002, 2.69627167e+002,
       5.63098022e+002, 2.08423523e+002, 5.16782654e+002,
       2.08424667e+002, 4.68059296e+002, 2.08661697e+002,
       4.16216431e+002, 2.09268982e+002, 3.62888763e+002,
       2.10013397e+002, 3.08458557e+002, 2.11074738e+002,
       2.53267990e+002, 2.12496582e+002, 1.99121384e+002,
       2.14005814e+002, 1.46551376e+002, 2.15851318e+002,
       5.62997437e+002, 1.57966492e+002, 5.16406494e+002,
       1.56580688e+002, 4.67334900e+002, 1.55756500e+002,
       4.15378235e+002, 1.55492874e+002, 3.62096710e+002,
       1.55498734e+002, 3.07522827e+002, 1.56133240e+002,
       2.52235214e+002, 1.57516571e+002, 1.97876328e+002,
       1.59318787e+002, 1.45078247e+002, 1.61638428e+002,
       5.62097168e+002, 1.07469536e+002, 5.15766846e+002,
       1.04902527e+002, 4.66562866e+002, 1.03045807e+002,
       4.14651459e+002, 1.01924713e+002, 3.61240662e+002,
       1.01357826e+002, 3.06746613e+002, 1.01582802e+002,
       2.51568024e+002, 1.02920105e+002, 1.97343307e+002,
       1.04941299e+002, 1.44756821e+002, 1.07737488e+002,
       5.68062500e+002, 3.73591125e+002, 5.25272644e+002,
       3.77019318e+002, 4.79870941e+002, 3.80086578e+002,
       4.31823730e+002, 3.83036652e+002, 3.81995758e+002,
       3.85271759e+002, 3.30728729e+002, 3.86998779e+002,
       2.78071167e+002, 3.88151031e+002, 2.26231567e+002,
       3.88669586e+002, 1.74855331e+002, 3.89197998e+002,
       5.69792542e+002, 3.27097382e+002, 5.26866028e+002,
       3.29362366e+002, 4.81278229e+002, 3.31532928e+002,
       4.32783203e+002, 3.33552185e+002, 3.82408234e+002,
       3.35186554e+002, 3.30427399e+002, 3.36404053e+002,
       2.77138519e+002, 3.37450958e+002, 2.24525131e+002,
       3.37957092e+002, 1.72285507e+002, 3.38503540e+002,
       5.70942749e+002, 2.79243713e+002, 5.27789307e+002,
       2.80073486e+002, 4.82146576e+002, 2.81226410e+002,
       4.33247375e+002, 2.82237427e+002, 3.82503662e+002,
       2.83062286e+002, 3.30138885e+002, 2.83794434e+002,
       2.76433228e+002, 2.84549286e+002, 2.23158783e+002,
       2.84981049e+002, 1.70520218e+002, 2.85720886e+002,
       5.71001953e+002, 2.30928329e+002, 5.27846863e+002,
       2.30519928e+002, 4.82114563e+002, 2.30268906e+002,
       4.33114563e+002, 2.30243515e+002, 3.82384857e+002,
       2.30311340e+002, 3.29870392e+002, 2.30454620e+002,
       2.76012634e+002, 2.30882156e+002, 2.22529434e+002,
       2.31355362e+002, 1.69742065e+002, 2.32063004e+002,
       5.70199036e+002, 1.82609772e+002, 5.27030884e+002,
       1.80973267e+002, 4.81193573e+002, 1.79573792e+002,
       4.32409821e+002, 1.78475616e+002, 3.81855530e+002,
       1.77680283e+002, 3.29641937e+002, 1.77092087e+002,
       2.75895782e+002, 1.77155502e+002, 2.22438889e+002,
       1.77605667e+002, 1.69884583e+002, 1.78365585e+002,
       5.69026245e+002, 1.34654831e+002, 5.26171570e+002,
       1.31798691e+002, 4.80653503e+002, 1.29171509e+002,
       4.31869904e+002, 1.27280067e+002, 3.81419739e+002,
       1.25591202e+002, 3.29466644e+002, 1.24407089e+002,
       2.76225342e+002, 1.24174736e+002, 2.23024109e+002,
       1.24463333e+002, 1.70838898e+002, 1.25398903e+002,
       4.73812897e+002, 6.94673386e+001, 4.74245453e+002,
       1.12387466e+002, 4.74243347e+002, 1.56034164e+002,
       4.73834778e+002, 2.00523651e+002, 4.72891602e+002,
       2.44457306e+002, 4.71412811e+002, 2.87981171e+002,
       4.69708252e+002, 3.30783173e+002, 4.67558228e+002,
       3.71818420e+002, 4.65495667e+002, 4.11996979e+002,
       4.31027649e+002, 6.75546722e+001, 4.31269440e+002,
       1.10960022e+002, 4.31185486e+002, 1.55113556e+002,
       4.30830139e+002, 2.00061066e+002, 4.30168427e+002,
       2.44456863e+002, 4.29107544e+002, 2.88479645e+002,
       4.27829071e+002, 3.31813507e+002, 4.26131653e+002,
       3.73071228e+002, 4.24718811e+002, 4.13476563e+002,
       3.86868805e+002, 6.61982269e+001, 3.86895416e+002,
       1.09904411e+002, 3.86690216e+002, 1.54396423e+002,
       3.86368591e+002, 1.99800369e+002, 3.85792206e+002,
       2.44538574e+002, 3.85117279e+002, 2.88826447e+002,
       3.84405273e+002, 3.32408020e+002, 3.83303772e+002,
       3.74074097e+002, 3.82477448e+002, 4.14638977e+002,
       3.41941437e+002, 6.54462357e+001, 3.41628204e+002,
       1.09383698e+002, 3.41402344e+002, 1.54105545e+002,
       3.41168854e+002, 1.99655045e+002, 3.40816681e+002,
       2.44469910e+002, 3.40516937e+002, 2.88975800e+002,
       3.40365662e+002, 3.32670990e+002, 3.39935211e+002,
       3.74465759e+002, 3.39847626e+002, 4.14742279e+002,
       2.96694000e+002, 6.56859589e+001, 2.96075226e+002,
       1.09505333e+002, 2.95704895e+002, 1.54202652e+002,
       2.95653107e+002, 1.99734131e+002, 2.95589661e+002,
       2.44549530e+002, 2.95629547e+002, 2.88889496e+002,
       2.96138733e+002, 3.32610931e+002, 2.96520905e+002,
       3.74608551e+002, 2.96987091e+002, 4.14774902e+002,
       2.51414978e+002, 6.65755463e+001, 2.50681854e+002,
       1.10189331e+002, 2.50183380e+002, 1.54658005e+002,
       2.50331161e+002, 2.00073761e+002, 2.50590790e+002,
       2.44719513e+002, 2.51083817e+002, 2.88868286e+002,
       2.52134262e+002, 3.32266937e+002, 2.53097809e+002,
       3.74022491e+002, 2.54404007e+002, 4.14018066e+002,
       1.49524078e+002, 1.27699501e+002, 1.89511658e+002,
       1.25816605e+002, 2.31050888e+002, 1.24260918e+002,
       2.74076721e+002, 1.23023209e+002, 3.17643005e+002,
       1.22288109e+002, 3.61785889e+002, 1.22105164e+002,
       4.06142670e+002, 1.22401566e+002, 4.49623962e+002,
       1.23246025e+002, 4.92677216e+002, 1.24087708e+002,
       1.48706085e+002, 1.69077423e+002, 1.88827805e+002,
       1.67750443e+002, 2.30439865e+002, 1.66769333e+002,
       2.73830933e+002, 1.65871170e+002, 3.17596741e+002,
       1.65410919e+002, 3.61983459e+002, 1.65327866e+002,
       4.06748322e+002, 1.65463974e+002, 4.50450226e+002,
       1.66126526e+002, 4.93614655e+002, 1.66970413e+002,
       1.48312607e+002, 2.11499451e+002, 1.88574097e+002,
       2.10860214e+002, 2.30130676e+002, 2.10261612e+002,
       2.73557709e+002, 2.09837143e+002, 3.17542572e+002,
       2.09633057e+002, 3.62091248e+002, 2.09732620e+002,
       4.06934570e+002, 2.09926758e+002, 4.50914612e+002,
       2.10320221e+002, 4.94044495e+002, 2.10900925e+002,
       1.48613831e+002, 2.53997177e+002, 1.88797791e+002,
       2.53912842e+002, 2.30240204e+002, 2.53975067e+002,
       2.73746704e+002, 2.54010208e+002, 3.17718262e+002,
       2.54106003e+002, 3.62188965e+002, 2.54205475e+002,
       4.06908783e+002, 2.54317505e+002, 4.50824951e+002,
       2.54539490e+002, 4.93825714e+002, 2.54753876e+002,
       1.49541687e+002, 2.96404175e+002, 1.89357727e+002,
       2.97117523e+002, 2.30807007e+002, 2.97805603e+002,
       2.74325470e+002, 2.97966522e+002, 3.18042206e+002,
       2.98304535e+002, 3.62105774e+002, 2.98552643e+002,
       4.06672272e+002, 2.98572418e+002, 4.50363068e+002,
       2.98569550e+002, 4.93109894e+002, 2.98516205e+002,
       1.50883698e+002, 3.38493195e+002, 1.90633621e+002,
       3.39862610e+002, 2.31920990e+002, 3.40869415e+002,
       2.74971252e+002, 3.41453766e+002, 3.18235229e+002,
       3.41952637e+002, 3.62063477e+002, 3.42314026e+002,
       4.06098938e+002, 3.42221802e+002, 4.49477386e+002,
       3.42063812e+002, 4.91864716e+002, 3.41727600e+002,
       2.36129852e+002, 3.92798004e+002, 2.34999939e+002,
       3.56118683e+002, 2.34376099e+002, 3.18607025e+002,
       2.33822159e+002, 2.80400696e+002, 2.33565445e+002,
       2.42213104e+002, 2.33583069e+002, 2.03937286e+002,
       2.34028824e+002, 1.65756607e+002, 2.34613373e+002,
       1.28586639e+002, 2.35190308e+002, 9.18279037e+001,
       2.73031616e+002, 3.93267242e+002, 2.72295166e+002,
       3.56342743e+002, 2.71799347e+002, 3.18847412e+002,
       2.71418854e+002, 2.80287872e+002, 2.71161469e+002,
       2.41881134e+002, 2.71248962e+002, 2.03348145e+002,
       2.71379303e+002, 1.64895874e+002, 2.71946045e+002,
       1.27450935e+002, 2.72322418e+002, 9.06900787e+001,
       3.10670715e+002, 3.93568848e+002, 3.10389160e+002,
       3.56545959e+002, 3.10084625e+002, 3.18814514e+002,
       3.09801544e+002, 2.80242737e+002, 3.09678711e+002,
       2.41574814e+002, 3.09779663e+002, 2.02989838e+002,
       3.09842712e+002, 1.64338043e+002, 3.10076782e+002,
       1.26870911e+002, 3.10243286e+002, 8.98413315e+001,
       3.48618134e+002, 3.93563202e+002, 3.48617065e+002,
       3.56472382e+002, 3.48608795e+002, 3.18855621e+002,
       3.48544556e+002, 2.80011017e+002, 3.48556396e+002,
       2.41388168e+002, 3.48585388e+002, 2.02692429e+002,
       3.48435089e+002, 1.64099731e+002, 3.48442902e+002,
       1.26549957e+002, 3.48338043e+002, 8.98002014e+001,
       3.86625610e+002, 3.93188599e+002, 3.87047729e+002,
       3.56377594e+002, 3.87306274e+002, 3.18714752e+002,
       3.87337799e+002, 2.79868896e+002, 3.87402740e+002,
       2.41228760e+002, 3.87295166e+002, 2.02695313e+002,
       3.87030273e+002, 1.64203415e+002, 3.86741211e+002,
       1.26606262e+002, 3.86337311e+002, 8.99655075e+001,
       4.24534088e+002, 3.92702545e+002, 4.25310822e+002,
       3.55900452e+002, 4.25869019e+002, 3.18160614e+002,
       4.25909790e+002, 2.79615753e+002, 4.25977295e+002,
       2.41165100e+002, 4.25826477e+002, 2.02876389e+002,
       4.25331665e+002, 1.64527618e+002, 4.24775787e+002,
       1.27097328e+002, 4.23985138e+002, 9.08176651e+001,
       1.79142670e+002, 1.58573654e+002, 2.12791580e+002,
       1.56291031e+002, 2.47140106e+002, 1.54265656e+002,
       2.82607300e+002, 1.52373688e+002, 3.18175507e+002,
       1.50692184e+002, 3.54185852e+002, 1.49404175e+002,
       3.90455200e+002, 1.48229370e+002, 4.26106689e+002,
       1.47507843e+002, 4.61576141e+002, 1.46712479e+002,
       1.80388336e+002, 1.93027603e+002, 2.14026459e+002,
       1.91128204e+002, 2.48376541e+002, 1.89414978e+002,
       2.83795807e+002, 1.87720856e+002, 3.19472473e+002,
       1.86192383e+002, 3.55483826e+002, 1.84929199e+002,
       3.91970764e+002, 1.83747040e+002, 4.27654572e+002,
       1.82931534e+002, 4.63295227e+002, 1.81977234e+002,
       1.81914261e+002, 2.27955460e+002, 2.15291260e+002,
       2.26512482e+002, 2.49628265e+002, 2.25067520e+002,
       2.85066406e+002, 2.23593185e+002, 3.20846680e+002,
       2.22337708e+002, 3.56862885e+002, 2.21191040e+002,
       3.93279907e+002, 2.19905640e+002, 4.29202271e+002,
       2.18870361e+002, 4.64728424e+002, 2.17972977e+002,
       1.83496948e+002, 2.62963226e+002, 2.16930527e+002,
       2.61755219e+002, 2.51115829e+002, 2.60777222e+002,
       2.86553406e+002, 2.59500336e+002, 3.22299896e+002,
       2.58380737e+002, 3.58307648e+002, 2.57236694e+002,
       3.94551819e+002, 2.56009125e+002, 4.30358948e+002,
       2.54925797e+002, 4.65684998e+002, 2.54021484e+002,
       1.85461685e+002, 2.97687378e+002, 2.18712234e+002,
       2.96999207e+002, 2.52770218e+002, 2.96270752e+002,
       2.88213776e+002, 2.95168213e+002, 3.23698334e+002,
       2.94233032e+002, 3.59477722e+002, 2.93170715e+002,
       3.95647766e+002, 2.91897400e+002, 4.31309845e+002,
       2.90856995e+002, 4.66494110e+002, 2.89726410e+002,
       1.87661331e+002, 3.32186188e+002, 2.20767746e+002,
       3.31906250e+002, 2.54839096e+002, 3.31398651e+002,
       2.89963745e+002, 3.30524139e+002, 3.25207642e+002,
       3.29771820e+002, 3.60686035e+002, 3.28762695e+002,
       3.96576447e+002, 3.27542206e+002, 4.31994415e+002,
       3.26294189e+002, 4.66894653e+002, 3.24949921e+002,
       2.03543015e+002, 1.77473557e+002, 2.32777847e+002,
       1.74712509e+002, 2.62628723e+002, 1.72331970e+002,
       2.93045898e+002, 1.69686768e+002, 3.23527618e+002,
       1.67496246e+002, 3.54206787e+002, 1.65446075e+002,
       3.85180176e+002, 1.63360580e+002, 4.15484253e+002,
       1.61536423e+002, 4.45720947e+002, 1.59896164e+002,
       2.05864395e+002, 2.07228104e+002, 2.35242096e+002,
       2.04699326e+002, 2.64853973e+002, 2.02407455e+002,
       2.95353882e+002, 1.99972321e+002, 3.25811890e+002,
       1.97671921e+002, 3.56471252e+002, 1.95763168e+002,
       3.87280548e+002, 1.93597977e+002, 4.17615814e+002,
       1.91867371e+002, 4.48018677e+002, 1.90067413e+002,
       2.08421249e+002, 2.37166977e+002, 2.37513824e+002,
       2.34982773e+002, 2.67261261e+002, 2.32802841e+002,
       2.97555817e+002, 2.30466080e+002, 3.28118103e+002,
       2.28462463e+002, 3.58699707e+002, 2.26417038e+002,
       3.89468842e+002, 2.24356827e+002, 4.19895996e+002,
       2.22421921e+002, 4.50077850e+002, 2.20683517e+002,
       2.11095444e+002, 2.66940186e+002, 2.40241348e+002,
       2.64970093e+002, 2.69563019e+002, 2.63153290e+002,
       2.99863464e+002, 2.60983551e+002, 3.30282440e+002,
       2.58911560e+002, 3.60724792e+002, 2.56935730e+002,
       3.91487915e+002, 2.54799423e+002, 4.21789093e+002,
       2.52929688e+002, 4.51818481e+002, 2.51059357e+002,
       2.13829117e+002, 2.96591217e+002, 2.42742859e+002,
       2.94884583e+002, 2.72209076e+002, 2.93215668e+002,
       3.02402985e+002, 2.91230591e+002, 3.32536072e+002,
       2.89165192e+002, 3.62860901e+002, 2.87413605e+002,
       3.93481842e+002, 2.85199615e+002, 4.23728851e+002,
       2.83277496e+002, 4.53453094e+002, 2.81229309e+002,
       2.16799316e+002, 3.25975220e+002, 2.45605515e+002,
       3.24619904e+002, 2.74777344e+002, 3.22958679e+002,
       3.04762817e+002, 3.21008057e+002, 3.34797150e+002,
       3.19291443e+002, 3.65005798e+002, 3.17295044e+002,
       3.95311981e+002, 3.15296021e+002, 4.25312592e+002,
       3.13086945e+002, 4.54931152e+002, 3.11027130e+002,
       2.60550232e+002, 3.70739563e+002, 2.59674011e+002,
       3.42115936e+002, 2.58910492e+002, 3.13278015e+002,
       2.58195618e+002, 2.84013580e+002, 2.57727173e+002,
       2.55017166e+002, 2.57326263e+002, 2.25760986e+002,
       2.57096619e+002, 1.96577972e+002, 2.57031860e+002,
       1.68026199e+002, 2.56873383e+002, 1.39550308e+002,
       2.89019318e+002, 3.70481354e+002, 2.88355560e+002,
       3.41833252e+002, 2.87601471e+002, 3.12872925e+002,
       2.87057190e+002, 2.83485535e+002, 2.86599762e+002,
       2.54255096e+002, 2.86174438e+002, 2.25023285e+002,
       2.85775940e+002, 1.95715347e+002, 2.85577087e+002,
       1.66989502e+002, 2.85395477e+002, 1.38597382e+002,
       3.18072754e+002, 3.70118317e+002, 3.17432709e+002,
       3.41398743e+002, 3.16917267e+002, 3.12476044e+002,
       3.16284363e+002, 2.83001587e+002, 3.15799072e+002,
       2.53725845e+002, 3.15411957e+002, 2.24337708e+002,
       3.15070374e+002, 1.95034119e+002, 3.14736847e+002,
       1.66195313e+002, 3.14439789e+002, 1.37797058e+002,
       3.47083588e+002, 3.69678101e+002, 3.46717987e+002,
       3.40949524e+002, 3.46185303e+002, 3.12009857e+002,
       3.45728088e+002, 2.82454071e+002, 3.45226624e+002,
       2.53109863e+002, 3.44883606e+002, 2.23839539e+002,
       3.44373535e+002, 1.94399933e+002, 3.43879852e+002,
       1.65690643e+002, 3.43438629e+002, 1.37252930e+002,
       3.76341522e+002, 3.68972321e+002, 3.76086884e+002,
       3.40412842e+002, 3.75708893e+002, 3.11398376e+002,
       3.75143494e+002, 2.81901520e+002, 3.74762970e+002,
       2.52577988e+002, 3.74223969e+002, 2.23348221e+002,
       3.73600891e+002, 1.93979538e+002, 3.72983917e+002,
       1.65201294e+002, 3.72517273e+002, 1.36871033e+002,
       4.05512115e+002, 3.68243225e+002, 4.05366333e+002,
       3.39678650e+002, 4.05090027e+002, 3.10679108e+002,
       4.04612366e+002, 2.81203522e+002, 4.04152649e+002,
       2.52051605e+002, 4.03539703e+002, 2.22930420e+002,
       4.02903351e+002, 1.93625381e+002, 4.02272827e+002,
       1.65004440e+002, 4.01353333e+002, 1.36796814e+002 ]
```

Im running it under windows with visual studio 2013 and the OpenCV version is 3.1.0-dev

Comment: ok i got it, instead of std::vector< cv::Mat > rvecs, tvecs; it must be std::vector< cv::Vec3d > rvecs, tvecs;